# Count number of records within the same time period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to count the total number of records that have been added in at a specific time. Below is a sample of my data.

```html
CNTR_N        LOAD_VESSEL_M    VOYAGE_OUT_N
HGTU 4615032 opgqqun          039E
TCNU 5590060 plq jpxxqyi  016E12
PCIU 1189368 iunpj igspnw  310N
CLHU 3193420 qpji oi          735S
RFSU 2000199 unqy ihpj        003NN
OOLU 1543519 mmaq ywclh  004E11
TFTU 8600600 epn vpu 490      W037
MSKU 5414708 syyhvmfyn  1708

SNAP_DT
2017-04-25 20:00:00.000
2017-04-25 20:00:00.000
2017-04-25 20:00:00.000
2017-04-25 20:00:00.000
2017-05-03 16:00:00.000
2017-05-03 16:00:00.000
2017-05-03 16:00:00.000
2017-05-03 16:00:00.000
```

Below is my desired output. I am trying to get the No_of_records column.

```html
SNAP_DT                  No_of_records
2017-04-25 20:00:00.000       4
2017-05-03 16:00:00.000       4
```

Do any of you have ideas on how to get the above output? Would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use `Group By` clause with aggregate function `Count`.

Assuming your table name is `table1`, below is the query that will return your desired result.

```
SELECT  snap_dt, Count(*)
FROM    table1
GROUP BY snap_dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
SNAP_DT
,COUNT(*)
FROM data
GROUP BY SNAP_DT
```